# Error using catch/throw inside for loop - unmatched "end"?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I am reading ["The Ruby Programming Language"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) and wanted to try the example provided in the book (Chapter 6, Altering Control Flow, catch and throw) for using catch/throw to break out of nested loops:

```
for matrix in data do 
  catch :missing_data do
    for row in matrix do 
      for value in row do
        throw :missing_data unless value
        puts value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I defined data as an array of three matrices:

> data
>    => [[[2, 3, 7], [8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 4]], [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", false, "e"], ["f", "g", nil]], [["abc", "def"], ["ghi", "jkl"]]]

However when I try the code in IRB (version 1.9.3p327), I get an "unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end" error.  I've tried playing around with the code and have discovered that it works if I remove the outmost (i.e. for) loop, but with the loop I get the error.  To double check, I created a simpler loop:

```
for i in [1,2,3] do
  catch :two do
    if i==2 then throw :two end
  end
end
```

Again, I get the same situation: error with the for loop, no error without the for loop (in fact, using IRB, I don't get the chance to enter the last 'end', but get the error after entering the fourth line above).

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need an `end` after your `unless` statement.

Comment: @BlaineOmega Why? In any case, wouldn't explain the other code chunk's issue.

Comment: Are you using psudeocode for these examples?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.  The modifier form of `unless` (i.e. _code_ unless _condition_) doesn't require an `end`.  I also get the same error with the second example that doesn't have an `unless` clause (I didn't use the modifier form in that example).

Comment: I think the problem is the `do`. You don't need `do` with the `for`. You could put: `for i in [1,2,3] catch :two...`

Comment: @TKNY I don't get this error. Is it *all* the code? My hunch is that it isn't. Please try to reproduce on http://ideone.com (If it can't be reproduced there, but can be reproduced locally, state that.)

Comment: @TKNY I cannot reproduce in the 1.9.3 version used on ideone.com; it would be interesting if this works/fails-to-work between different builds .. a failing/success table would be handy.

Comment: Check my edit. This is an IRB error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be build and/or environment-dependent (I lean towards environment):

- Original code works when I execute it from within Sublime Text 2
- Original code works when running via `ruby` from command line
- Original code does *not* work when I type it in to `irb`

Inside `irb` dropping the `do` in the outer `for`, or using `{}` for the `catch`, works:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p327                                                                              Using /Users/Dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> data = [[[2, 3, 7], [8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 4]], [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", false, "e"], ["f", "g", nil]], [["abc", "def"], ["ghi", "jkl"]]]
irb(main):002:0> for matrix in data do
irb(main):003:1*   catch(:missing_data) {
irb(main):004:2*     for row in matrix do 
irb(main):005:3*       for value in row do
irb(main):006:4*         throw :missing_data unless value
irb(main):007:4>         puts value
irb(main):008:4>       end
irb(main):009:3>     end
irb(main):010:2>   }
irb(main):011:1> end
2
3
7
8
9
10
0
1
4
a
b
c
d
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

Comment: `{` and `}` are bad form for multiline blocks, and this still doesn't work.

Comment: @Linuxios It works perfectly fine for me under p327. Bad form or not, it is one of the options, as is the other I list.

Comment: True. +1. It's still better to use `do...end` if possible.

Comment: @Linuxios Definitely agree, at least in terms of writing canonical Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `do` with `for ... in ...`. It's actually a syntax error. That's your problem. Nothing to do with `catch`/`throw`. Just remove the `do` from all your `for` loops.

Working example:

```
for matrix in data 
  catch :missing_data do
    for row in matrix 
      for value in row
        throw :missing_data unless value
        puts value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

This is an IRB problem. When I put your code in a script, it works perfectly.

Comment: @pst: Same. I think you're actually missing an `end`.

Comment: It seems like it *might* be a funny difference between builds (I cannot reproduce on ideone which uses 1.9.3.something) .. still would be nice to track down the regression or acceptance point.

Comment: @pst: I don't think it is. Hold on, let me test on 1.9.2 and rbx

Comment: The `do` isn't a syntax error; it's optional&ndash;but seems to have issues in `irb`. Looks like we discovered the same thing.

Comment: @DaveNewton: That's good. Consistency means we're both right :).

Comment: @Linuxios: You are absolutely right that removing the `do` solves the problem.  That's interesting, since `for` loops actually work with `do`, at least in my version of IRB (the book also uses `do` in its syntax when introducing `for` loops, but not in all its examples I now notice).  I wonder why the `do` suddenly causes a problem with `catch` and `throw`?  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @TKNY: What's you're `ruby -v`? Are you in RVM?

Comment: @Linuxios Orrrrrr both dumb! I tried across all 1.9.3 versions and a couple of 1.9.2 versions; all show the issue in `irb`.

Comment: @TKNY: it's a block catching issue. It would probably be the same with a method like `each`. By the way, it's idiomatic to use `each`, not `for`.

Comment: @Linuxios: I'm using IRB version 1.9.3.

Comment: @TKNY: Same. Are you using RVM? And Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: @Linuxios: I am using RVM on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, drop the `do` from your `for` statements.